# Getting event notifications for Azure Blob objects created in the past

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I plan on using Azure Event Grid to get notifications when Blob objects are created. If my service goes down and comes back up, will I get notifications of Blob objects that were created while my service was down? I would prefer not to get notifications of Blob objects that were created while my service was down.

Answer (score 0):

The document for [Retry schedule and duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule-and-duration) described the types of destination endpoints and errors for which retry doesn't happen.

As you can see in the table of the [Failure codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#failure-codes) the code **503 Service Unavailable** is retrying a message delivery after 30 seconds or more.

It will be nice to have a capability for each subscription to control a retry policy based on the status code, but for now I can see the following workaround:

- Use the [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-azure-api-management-for-serverless-architectures/) for handling a properly return status code back to the AEG, in other words, the APIM will mapped the stratus code 503 from your service to the status code 403 back to the AEG. Note, this APIM mediator will also handle a webhook validation for AEG subscription.

I do recommend to enable a dead-lettering feature for auditing non delivered messages during when your service has been down.